# How do I keep latest 4 backup file and delete the older one

Tags: linux, backup, logrotate

How do I keep the latest 4 backup files and delete the older one?

```
backup-Y-M-D.zip
backup-Y-M-D.zip
backup-Y-M-D.zip
backup-Y-M-D.zip
.
.
backup-Y-M-D.zip
```

There are about 80 files having .zip extension all I wanted to do is to keep the latest 8 files according to the date on which created. I also tried logrotate but failed to rotate logs as it is not doing anything. Below down is the config file of logrotate.

```
/root/test/*.zip {
    daily
    missingok
    extension .zip
    rotate 4
    nocompress 
}
```

Comment: What's the names of the files after rotation? The `extension .zip` configuration ensures they still have the `.zip` extenison, right? This probably means the rotated logs will be rotated again later?

Comment: Try it with `logrotate -d -f logrotate.conf`. In that way, you will see what would logrotate do. I think it can be done with logrotate. Maybe you need to wait a few rotations for everything to settle. When you start it for the first time, all files are new, and it does not know which ones to delete.

Answer (score 1):

That config doesn't look right; for starters `logrotate` would be expecting an actual filename (like `/root/test/backup.zip`), not a wildcard**<sup>1</sup>**.  And the files themselves would need to be named in a format that `logrotate` is expecting -- or rather, `logrotate` would need to be told to expect the naming that the files have (otherwise it's going to assume `file.1.ext` and similar).  This might be possible by specifying the date format but it feels like you're bending the tool to a purpose for which it was not designed.

Something like this is probably what you're after:

```
find '/root/test' -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'backup-*.zip' -print0 \
  | sort -rz \
  | tail -zn+5 \
  | xargs -t0 -n1 true rm
```

This is hobbled for safety -- remove the word `true` on the last time to make it active.  You could also remove `-n1`, since that's just there for readability of output.

You'd then need something to trigger this file ageing process.  Usually, and ideally, this would be part of the same process that creates the backup file, so it happens at exactly the moment it is needed.  If this is not possible (for instance, if the files are being transferred in via some remote process), then you'd be looking at creating a `crontab` entry to run it on a schedule.

---

**<sup>1</sup>** Just to qualify this, `logrotate` *does* accept wildcards, but they are not treated in a manner that is useful here -- each matched file would be treated as the first in a set of items that need to be rotated.

It's probably just as well it's not working for you, or I think your files would end up in a bit of a mess and would need to be renamed.